# Receiving faxes on printer even while computer is shut down?

Tags: printer, fax

I normally send faxes with a very old fax machine and I was thinking it takes so much time for every fax to be scanned for all the numbers so I would like to send faxes with a printer.

I already have an all-in-one printer, it can scan and print, but I have the document I want to fax on my computer already, so there is no need to scan. Now, the question is if I buy a fax capable printer, will it receive my faxes even when the computer is shut down or do I need to keep the computer on?

What I really want is a way to

1. send a lot of faxes to a lot of numbers as fast as possible (the document already in the computer through scan or sending)
2. to be able to receive the fax in my computer (even while off) so I can print it with my printer

If both are possible then what requirements do I need? Also, I could not find any info on the internet about receiving faxes on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It will be connected through the phone line and be able to function independently of your computer.

Comment: Make sure the printer can a) receive the faxes into memory (without printing) and b) download them to the PC later.